# Is there a way to output video signal from SuperMicro E100-8Q?

Tags: iot, supermicro

For a research project, we are given some SuperMicro E100-8Q machines and we would like to try installing a Linux distro over them. However, the device only has RS232, RS485/Analog/DIO, USB, and ethernet interfaces. Is there a way to convert any of these to VGA?

Thank you

Comment: None of those standards supports video.  You could remote into them from a device that does with RS232 though. This of course requires that they have an OS configured.

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you say VGA you mean a display and windows. Yes, you can. You can run X11 forwarding over SSH to run Xwindows, but that being said if you have never run Linux before and you are a newbie, it will be quite a bit of a learning curve. EAsier just to ssh in a run everything through the command-line.